# pure javascript highlight string in html document across elements node to support old browser ie6+

Tags: javascript, html, regex, highlight

lets say we have this html string :

```
 var input ="the next text: <span>i want </span>to <br>highlight,  thank you";
```

and i want to match the whole search string :
"i want to highlight" the output i want  like this :

```
 var output ="the next text: <span><mark>i want</mark></span><mark>to </mark><br><mark>highlight</mark>,  thank you";
```

or like this :

```
 var input ="the next text: <mark><span>i want </span>to <br>highlight<mark>,  thank you";
```

the next code is kind what i want

---

```
function highlight(text) {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
            new RegExp('what right regex to put here', 'gi'),
            '<mark>$&</mark>'
        );
    } 
highlight("i want to highlight");
```

Comment: You don't want to use regex on HTML. Explain what existing highlighter libraries you have tried and what did not work with them on an older browser.

Comment: there is mark.js that support across elements node but it does not support old browser like ie6

Comment: Have you tried others, too? Or maybe an old version of mark.js?

Comment: yes i did but they don't work like i want..

Comment: the only one works is mark.js but it is designed for modern browser

Comment: pls give me complete example

Comment: i want exact match of the whole string...

Comment: there is no old version for mark.js i event tried to use pollyfill scripts  but it didn't work

Comment: its kinda works but its not a complete solution i want to highlight only this:"i want to highlight"

Comment: *"there is no old version for mark.js"* No true. You can download all their versions back to 1.0.0 from github.

Comment: give me the link plz for old version i couldn't find one that work with ie6+